# AWS Sam Hello World Failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I cannot pass the hello world deployment of sam which can work months ago

- What I did

```
sam deploy --guided
    Looking for config file [samconfig.toml] :  Not found

    Setting default arguments for 'sam deploy'
    =========================================
    Stack Name [sam-app]:
    AWS Region [eu-west-2]:
    #Shows you resources changes to be deployed and require a 'Y' to initiate deploy
    Confirm changes before deploy [y/N]: y
    #SAM needs permission to be able to create roles to connect to the resources in your template
    Allow SAM CLI IAM role creation [Y/n]: y
    #Preserves the state of previously provisioned resources when an operation fails
    Disable rollback [y/N]: y
    HelloWorldFunction may not have authorization defined, Is this okay? [y/N]: y
    Save arguments to configuration file [Y/n]: y
    SAM configuration file [samconfig.toml]:
    SAM configuration environment [default]:
```

- What I got

```
    Looking for resources needed for deployment:
    Creating the required resources...
Error: Failed to create managed resources: Waiter StackCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state: For expression "Stacks[].StackStatus" we matched expected path: "ROLLBACK_FAILED" at least once
```

- What I tried

1. brew install aws-sam-cli again
2. delete cloudformation stack and sam deploy -g again
3. give myself AdministratorAccess and tried above steps again
4. reset AWS credential with a new token and key
5. try using sam installed by either x86 brew and arm brew (I am using M1 mac)
6. upgrade aws-cli
7. read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436947/aws-sam-deployed-error-under-hello-world-template)

Please anyone help..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I cannot succeed with `aws s3api list-buckets`(Access Denied)
I tried to create a new access key and it still doesn't work
It seems the user is totally broken
Finally, I created a new user and everything is back to normal

Thanks for the [guide here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4109)